# Get the latest named folder from directory path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script, and I'm really new to this. What I want to happen is the code will look inside the "irc_workspace" location for specific projects. I'll be passing the project name into it.

All the folders in the directory are dated "YYYY-MM-DD" and I need to get the most recent dated folder not just the last modified. I'm not sure how to do this? Your help is appreciated.

For example inside my directory I have many folders all dated 2023-06-19, 2023-06-01, 2023-05-30. I need to retrieve the contents of 2023-06-19

```
# Before taking any sync action we need to remove the existing roundtrip folders from workspace and copy the latest roundtrip folder from Server.
    $pathToIRCServer = $pathToServer + $argDoorsFsEnd + "\Roundtrips"
    $latest = Get-ChildItem $pathToIRCServer | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    $latest.name
    '   '
    'Replace workspace folders with the latest folder on server.'
    Copy-Item -Path $latest -Recurse -Destination $WorkSpaceLocation -Container -Force
```

I tried modifying the Get-ChildItem

```
 $pathToIRCServer = $pathToServer + $argDoorsFsEnd + "\Roundtrips"
    $latest = Get-ChildItem $pathToIRCServer | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1
    $latest.name
=============================
$latest = (Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToServerFldr | Sort-Object -Descending -Property LastWriteTime | select -First 1)
    $latest_filename = $latest.Name 
=============================
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToServerFldr | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
    #'LatestName: " + $latest.name
```

Comment: Change from : $latest.name to : $latest.fullname  Fullname give entire path instead of just the filename.

Comment: I'm unable to sort and get the latest subfolder. It just returns the parent folder "Roundtrips" . I need to sort and acquire the folder with the latest date in file name.

Comment: The folder names contains dates and sorting by the string name should work : Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\temp' -Directory | Sort-Object $_.Name -Descending

Comment: I don't know why but this isn't working.  Get-ChildItem -Path 'M:\6A-BrakeServo\Roundtrip\' -Directory | Sort-Object $_.Name -Descending returns nothing. Is there a setting I need to make. I'm using PowerShell ISE to test

Comment: Either there is no directories in the path or the folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Got it thank you. I had a typo